# How to set request specific SQL session variable when loading data using Hibernate Native Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

In one of my team's Spring Boot application we are using Spring JPA with Hibernate as JPA provider. We have this `SQLExecutor` class as a repository which is autowired in the request handler. The following is the skeleton structure of the class:

```
@Repository
public class SQLExecutor {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Value("${query.fetch.size}")
private Integer queryFetchSize;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Stream<Map<String, Object>> executeSqlStreamed(String dbQuerySql, List<Object> params) {
    Query query = constructQueryForStream(dbQuerySql, params);
    return query.getResultStream();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Map<String, Object>> executeSql(String dbQuerySql, List<Object> params) {
    Query query = constructQueryForStream(dbQuerySql, params);
    return query.getResultList();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, Object> executeSqlSingleResult(String dbQuerySql, List<Object> params) {
    Query query = constructQuery(dbQuerySql, params);
    return (Map<String, Object>) query.getSingleResult();
}

private Query constructQueryForStream(String dbQuerySql, List<Object> params) {
    Query query = constructQuery(dbQuerySql, params);
    query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, queryFetchSize);
    return query;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Query constructQuery(String dbQuerySql, List<Object> params) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(dbQuerySql);
    query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
    int paramIndex = 0;
    if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
        for (Object paramValue : params) {
            query.setParameter(++paramIndex, paramValue);
        }
    }
    return query;
}
}
```

All the DB query strings are `SELECT` statements, because the application only provides read access to only a specific category of tables. The datasource is Tomcat JDBC pooled data source and the underlying database is a SQL based database that supports connection specific session variables. Both `datasource` and `entitymanagerfactorbean` are configured in a different `@Configuration` file.

### Question

I have to pass a token from authentication context of the request to the db layer as a session variable, which would authenticate whether the application user trying to access a particular resource has access to that resource or not, using something similar to stored procedures. So basically, every time a user requests to read a resource, a session variable needs to be set using a value from the context of that request, before making the actual `SELECT` query.

Now, I know how to extract the token, but what I want to understand is how to set it to the session variable whenever a db connection is initialized for that read request. From other applications of my team which are using JDBC directly instead of Hibernate JPA, it is simple enough like so:

```
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    stmt.executeUpdate("SET '" + variable + "' = '" + value + "'");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

But since JPA does not expose the connection object directly, how do I ensure the session variable is set to the same connection as the one being used to execute the select statement.

**Note:** I understand the connection object can be accessed by unwrapping `EntityManager` instance to underlying `Session` object and then using the `doReturningWork` method, but I think that is an anti-pattern and would make supporting streaming result set a manual effort which is detrimental to the application.